# angular subscribe to update method, when do you have to unsubscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am developing an angular application that uses rxjs.  All the examples I have seen have examples of how to subscribe and unsubscribe from read operations.  My scenario is an update operation.  I have the following code

```
       this.service.udpate(cliendId).subscribe(res => {
           console.log("success");
        }, err => console.log("error"));
```

This line of code is called every time the user clicks the update button.  My question is, do I need to unsubscribe from this since this is an update operation and if so where should I do it?

The `update` method returns  `Observable<FetchResult<T>>` from ApolloClient

Comment: Depends on how many events you want to get from this stream. If it's called every time user clicks the button, I guess you expect to get just one event and no more, until the button got clicked again (which triggers this line once again, but you expect to get just one event). If so, you can `take(1)` event, this completes the stream automatically after single event received: `this.service.udpate(cliendId).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(...)`.

Comment: I'm expecting only one even from this actually, not more than one, however not sure if there will be some memory leak if I don't unsubscribe and navigate away from this and comes back, I mean would the subscribe method get called twice ?

Comment: Subscribe will definitely be called twice or more times if you don't limit the stream: all the previous streams still alive while you don't complete / unsubscribe from them. I've posted a common answer, but I feel that I missed something important. Could you provide more details about what does the `this.service.udpate` actually do (is it an HTTP call, or socket subscription, or something else), when it emits values and any other useful info? So I can update my answer to cover your specific case.  Probably you should make architectural changes, I can't really say right now.

Comment: Would be really helpful, if you can describe the flow briefly, like "I open the page, click the button, which invokes `udpate` method from service. It makes an HTTP call and returns a single value (button becomes inactive  and no more clicks available). Change the route to any other, get back, click the button once again, which invokes `udpate` method from service that makes an HTTP call and returns a single value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily limit the count of received events in your stream via `take` operator (use `take(1)` for your case). It completes the stream automatically after the specified number of values received. Here you can see the difference between "unlimited" stream and another one with `take(1)`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-snhzh2?file=index.ts